# simulator based on llvm framework

Tags: llvm

Is there a plan to write processor simulator based on the llvm framework ? Or maybe there already a project that I am not familiar with ? There is already a compiler, assembler and linker but missing a simulator to run the execution file. I am already familiar with the bitcode emulation (lli) but it is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Are you looking for an open-source project, or a commercial framework?

Comment: I prefer open-source, but I can take commercial as well.